# Where to include the object id when POSTing form data for the object

Tags: django, forms, http, post, http-post

To POST data to the server for an object, one must provide the object's ID for lookup. Where to include the ID and send it to the server is something that has been bugging me. There are three options I have in mind:

1. Include the ID as part of the URL
2. Include the ID as part of the POST data
3. Put the ID in query string (I'm not sure if query string is allowed when doing a POST)

I use python/django for my server end.

Someone please comment on which one I should go with and why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it via the URL in most cases, particularly if you are creating a view to display an object. Furthermore, I'd use the slug (if there is one) instead of an ID as it looks better in Google SERP, it makes more sense semantically, and it is more readable for users.

Remember that you can easily reverse object's urls using `get_absolute_url()`, the `{% url ... %}` tag and the `reverse()` function. You won't be able to avail of these if you use query strings or Posts to display your objects.

Regarding query strings/parameters; I usually go by the rule of constructing the queryset with my URL, but filtering it with parameters. i.e. If I want to see all posts tagged with something, I get the main queryset via the URL `/posts/tagged/some_tag` and then drill them down where necessary with parameters; `/posts/tagged/some_tag?rating=2`

Regarding POST data; this should only really apply when you are presenting a form to edit an object. I would still use the URL to find and display the form (i.e. `/posts/my-post-slug/edit/`) and I would use parameters to control any options or features (i.e. `/posts/my-post/slug/edit/?highlight_required_fields=true`) but all the fields of the form would be submitted via POST

Comment: Timmy - Thanks for sharing your experience. I think they are excellent approach. Here, I got a django-specific question for you. Say I send some form data to `/posts/my-post/slug/edit/?highlight_required_fields=true` via POST, would I still be able to use `request.GET.get('highlight_required_fields')` to see the value for `highlight_required_fields`?

Comment: Yes. In your view you would have `highlight = request.GET.get("highlight", None)` or just `request.GET['highlight']`